# Horizontal alignment under a character (word)

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I am trying to align some text in the following way (shown below from a word processor):

[image: wordprocessor]

What is the best way to do this?  Should I use `makebox`es?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item{In outer space,\\
the change in pressure is dominated by unicorns at low temperature;\\
by gnomes at moderate temperature; and\\
by dwarves at high temperature.}
\item{Underwater,\\
the change in pressure is dominated by lemmings at low temperature;\\
by elves at moderate temperature; and\\
by trolls at high temperature.}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `\phantom` for example as follows:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\newcommand{\myplaceholder}{\phantom{the change in pressure is dominated }}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item{In outer space,\\
the change in pressure is dominated by unicorns at low temperature;\\
\myplaceholder by gnomes at moderate temperature; and\\
\myplaceholder by dwarves at high temperature.}
\item{Underwater,\\
the change in pressure is dominated by lemmings at low temperature;\\
\myplaceholder by elves at moderate temperature; and\\
\myplaceholder by trolls at high temperature.}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

---

Here is an alternative version using `\widthof` from the `calc` package in combination with `\hspace`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{calc}
\newlength{\mylength}
\setlength{\mylength}{\widthof{the change in pressure is dominated}}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item{In outer space,\\
the change in pressure is dominated by unicorns at low temperature;

\hspace{\mylength} by gnomes at moderate temperature; and

\hspace{\mylength} by dwarves at high temperature.}
\item{Underwater,\\
the change in pressure is dominated by lemmings at low temperature;

\hspace{\mylength} by elves at moderate temperature; and

\hspace{\mylength} by trolls at high temperature.}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

by use of the `tabular`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item   In outer space,\\
        the change in pressure is dominated 
            \begin{tabular}[t]{@{} l}
            by unicorns at low temperature;\\
            by gnomes at moderate temperature; and\\
            by dwarves at high temperature.
            \end{tabular}

\item   In outer space,\\
        the change in pressure is dominated
            \begin{tabular}[t]{@{} l}
            by unicorns at low temperature;\\
            by gnomes at moderate temperature; and\\
            by dwarves at high temperature.
            \end{tabular}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

With a `\Longunderstack`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\setstackEOL{\\}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item In outer space,\\
the change in pressure is dominated \Longunderstack[l]{%
by unicorns at low temperature;\\
by gnomes at moderate temperature; and\\
by dwarves at high temperature.}
\item Underwater,\\
the change in pressure is dominated \Longunderstack[l]{%
by lemmings at low temperature;\\
by elves at moderate temperature; and\\
by trolls at high temperature.}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This solution uses a `\parbox`.  Note that there really isn't enough room on the page for the "and."

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\sbox0{the change in pressure is dominated }% measure width
\item In outer space,\\
\usebox0\parbox[t]{\dimexpr \linewidth-\wd0}{% remaining space
by unicorns at low temperature;\\
by gnomes at moderate temperature; and\\
by dwarves at high temperature.}

\item Underwater,\\
\usebox0\parbox[t]{\dimexpr \linewidth-\wd0}{%
by lemmings at low temperature;\\
by elves at moderate temperature; and\\
by trolls at high temperature.}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```