# Load the geometry package without having it change the document margins

Tags: margins, geometry

I am using `\documentclass{book}` along with the [`libertine`](https://ctan.org/pkg/libertine?lang=en) and [`libertinust1math`](https://ctan.org/pkg/libertinust1math?lang=en) packages.

I would like to use the command `\phantom`, which is in the [`geometry`](https://ctan.org/pkg/geometry?lang=en) package (as seen in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/568062/15622)). However, as soon as I introduce the `geometry` package, the margins of my document change. This can be seen by compiling the following MWE in two ways: once with the `geometry` package loaded and once without.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[semibold,tt=false]{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore 
et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut 
aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse 
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa 
qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\end{document}
```

How can I load the `geometry` package *without* having it change the document margins?

Comment: `\phantom` is defined in the LaTeX kernel, so you don't need `geometry` to use it (that answer doesn't say that you need `geometry`;  it probably only loads it to change the margin for the example)

Comment: In case you (or any future readers) do need `geometry`, use `\usepackage[pass]{geometry}`.

Comment: The answer in the link you provided in no way claims that `\phantom` is a command provided by the `geometry` package.